# How to wrap object in proxy for debugging?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, proxy

I'm trying to wrap an object in order to identify who's changing it.  I've tried to do that with `Proxy` object, but I'm getting a weird error:

```
const wrap = object => {
    const handler = {
        get(obj, prop) {
            return wrap(obj[prop])            
        },
        set(obj, prop, value) {
            debugger;
            return Reflect.set(obj, prop, value)
        }
    };
    return new Proxy(object, handler)
}
```

I run `obj = wrap(obj)`, and then starting my function, but then an error is thrown:

```
TypeError: Cannot create proxy with a non-object as target or handler
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `obj` that you’re passing to `wrap`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox A regular object :) with some properties and data. Thanks for trying to help, posted my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that a property of `obj` isn't an object, the recursively wrapping won't work.
Checking whether the obj is an object or not needed:

```
const wrap = object => {
    const handler = {
        get(obj, prop) {
            return wrap(obj[prop])            
        },
        set(obj, prop, value) {
            debugger;
            return Reflect.set(obj, prop, value)
        }
    };
    return _.isObject(object) ? new Proxy(object, handler) : object
}
```

Comment: More precisely, the problem is that you are blindly calling `wrap` when getting a value. It seems better to put the check inside the `get`.